# Flink 1.2.0 jdbc read stream data from Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to use Flink 2.1.0 to read streaming data from mysql log table, however, it only read once then it will stop the process. I would like it to contiune read if there is incoming data and print it. Following is my code

```
public class Database {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // get the execution environment
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        TypeInformation[] fieldTypes = new TypeInformation[] { LONG_TYPE_INFO, STRING_TYPE_INFO };
        RowTypeInfo rowTypeInfo = new RowTypeInfo(fieldTypes);

        DataStreamSource source = env.createInput(
            JDBCInputFormat.buildJDBCInputFormat()
                    .setDrivername("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
                    .setDBUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/log_db")
                    .setUsername("root")
                    .setPassword("pass")
                    .setQuery("select id, SERVER_NAME from ERRORLOG")
                    .setRowTypeInfo(rowTypeInfo)
                    .finish()
        );
        source.print().setParallelism(1);
        env.execute("Error Log Data");
    }
}
```

I am using local internal run with maven:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.test.Database
```

Result:

```
09:15:56,394 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Freeing task resources for Source: Custom Source (1$
4) (41c66a6dfb97e1d024485f473617a342).
09:15:56,394 INFO  org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem                           - Ensuring all FileSystem streams are closed for Sour$
e: Custom Source (1/4)
09:15:56,394 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Sink: Unnamed (1/1) (5212fc2a570152c58ffe3d39d3d805$
0) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
09:15:56,394 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Freeing task resources for Sink: Unnamed (1/1) (521$
fc2a570152c58ffe3d39d3d805b0).
09:15:56,394 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Un-registering task and sending final execution sta$
e FINISHED to JobManager for task Source: Custom Source (41c66a6dfb97e1d024485f473617a342)
09:15:56,396 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Source: Custom Source (1/4) (41c66a6dfb97e1d024485f$
73617a342) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
09:15:56,396 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionClientActor      - 02/22/2017 09:15:56  Source: Custom Source(1/4) swi$
ched to FINISHED 
02/22/2017 09:15:56     Source: Custom Source(1/4) switched to FINISHED 
09:15:56,396 INFO  org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem                           - Ensuring all FileSystem streams are closed for Sink$
 Unnamed (1/1)
09:15:56,397 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager              - Un-registering task and sending final execution sta$
e FINISHED to JobManager for task Sink: Unnamed (5212fc2a570152c58ffe3d39d3d805b0)
09:15:56,398 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Sink: Unnamed (1/1) (5212fc2a570152c58ffe3d39d3d805$
0) switched from RUNNING to FINISHED.
09:15:56,398 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph        - Job Socket Window Data (0eb15d61031ede785e7ed21ead2$
ceea) switched from state RUNNING to FINISHED.
09:15:56,398 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionClientActor      - 02/22/2017 09:15:56  Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to 
FINISHED 
02/22/2017 09:15:56     Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to FINISHED 
09:15:56,405 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator     - Stopping checkpoint coordinator for job 0eb15d61031$
de785e7ed21ead21ceea
09:15:56,406 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionClientActor      - Terminate JobClientActor.
09:15:56,406 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClient                     - Job execution complete
09:15:56,408 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.FlinkMiniCluster         - Stopping FlinkMiniCluster.
09:15:56,405 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.StandaloneCompletedCheckpointStore  - Shutting down
```

Comment: The JDBCInputFormat was written for batch applications; there is currently no streaming JDBC connector in the flink project. You will have to create a source (that could internally use the JDBCInputFormat), however you will have to take care yourself that you only emit new values.

Comment: @ChesnaySchepler Thank you for reply, could you show me an example how to create a source for mysql? Also I read readFile API in Flink, maybe I can expose this table to an json API, and read file from it using stream?

Answer (score 1):

table data of mysql is fixed when start to query, so the job should be a flink batch job.

If you want to read the incoming data if there is incoming data, flink can not handle this kind of case, because flink does not know the incoming data unless you monitor binlog.

You have to use canal to sync up the binlog from mysql to kafka, and run a flink streaming job reading data from kafka. This is the best solution.